# destroy data in primefaces dialog after close from master page

Tags: jsf, primefaces, managed-bean

in my page have some commandButton that open dialog with table . 
table have 300 row and after close HTML dialog not destroy and persist in HTML page . 
i want destroy data in dialog after hide. and after click on commandButton repeat action load dialog and load data in dialog . 
I found this method

```xml
<p:ajax event="close" update="growl" listener="#{dialogBean.handleClose}"/>
```

but not know how can destroy dialog from facescontext.

Comment: You mean that you want to lighten your DOM Tree after closing the dialog, by removing the elements from the DOM TREE ? @Jeus

Comment: @HatemAlimam yes, i want remove data from table in dialog (HTML DOM from master page)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you have the following *dialog*

```xhtml
<p:dialog id="dialog" widgetVar="dlgVar" dynamic="true" >
  <p:ajax event="close" update="growl" listener="#{dialogBean.handleClose}"
   onstart="PF('dlgVar').content.empty()"/>
</p:dialog>
```

*Button*

```xhtml
<p:commandButton value="Button" 
                 onComplete="PF('dlgVar').show()" 
                 update="dialog">
```

or you can call `PF('dlgVar').content.empty()` in the `onHide` of the dialog, if you don't need an ajax request.

```xhtml
<p:dialog id="dialog" widgetVar="dlgVar" 
          dynamic="true"
         onHide="PF('dlgVar').content.empty()">
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: plz write method in manageBean  **dialogBean.handleClose**, thnx.

Comment: if you need only to empty the [DOM tree](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp), this would do it without any server side method.

Comment: I have updated the question, in the last code you can see there's no need for ajax request, just call it on the onHide, and you're okay. @Jeus

Comment: oh yes. after hide content of dialog destroy of page? is good, tanks.

Comment: How can I do the same but with `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("showDialog('dialogBox')")`

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help you.
Suppose you have a commandButton :

```
<p:commandButton id="button" value="Button" actionListener="#{dialogBean.populateDataTable}" onComplete="yourDialog.show()" update="@form">
```

Now your `<p:dialog>` will look like :

```
<p:dialog  widgetVar="yourDialog" dynamic="true" >
    <p:dataTable value="#{dialogBean.yourList}"..........> ...   </p:dataTable>
</p:dialog>
```

You have to populate dataTable's data in your actionlistaner. As your `<p:dataTable>` takes `yourList` of `dialogBean`, then fetch data of variable `yourList` from DB.

```
public void populateDataTable(ActionEvent event) {
    //Populate data here to be shown in `<p:dataTable>` inside `<p:dialog>`
    //yourList = new ArrayList<yourObject>();
    //allresult = fetchdataFromDB();
    //yourList.addAll(allresult);
}
```

Comment: my problem that here. How i can populate dataTable (command in populateDataTable)?

Comment: @Jeus I have updated my answer, let me know is it clear to you or not. Just populate the list/model(input for `<p:dataTable>`) in  `populateDataTable(ActionEvent event)` method.